# what happens when spark job fails?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose i am reading table from RDBMS and writing it in HDFS. Job is completed 48% successfully and after that it fails due to some reasons. What should be the next course of action here ? aa we cannot start reading from start again because it will be waste of time . so how to read only remaining records ?

```
Suppose i am reading a table from RDBMS and writing it in HDFS. Job is completed 48% successfully and after that it fails due to some reasons. What should be the next course of action here ? aa we cannot start reading from start again because it will be waste of time . so how to read only remaining records ?
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it depends on the type of failure, and all the factors of your cluster (replication factor...). In general, you should refer to transactions if you want write atomicity, look [here](https://docs.qubole.com/en/latest/user-guide/engines/spark/spark-acid/index.html) for more.